# is there a way of reversing events and creating new ones with jquery when dealing with event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

I'm creating a navbar with multiple dropdowns and using jquery, each has an event listener which closes and opens them. I then added an overlay to cover the background when a dropdown is open. The overlay works as expected but the problem is, when i click the item to open the dropdown, the overlay opens well until i click the next element, then the overlay starts behaving unexpectedly ie. i click first item, overlay opens, i click the next, it closes and keeps doing that for every item i click. basically it reverses the order. I've spent the whole day on the internet, asked even chatgpt, bard and bingchat and its still problematic. Here is the my code.

I added the isDropdownOpen and if statement later to try and check whether it is open to close the overlay but the problem persisted. Ive added and removed so many lines of code i can barely remember them. I thought of trying to make the overlay revert to previous values then redoing it, hence the poorly worded question but i cant quite figure it out.

**Code Snippet**

```js
var isDropdownOpen = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
  $('.dropdown a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.hide').slideToggle();
    isDropdownOpen = !isDropdownOpen
    if (isDropdownOpen) {
      $('#cn-overlay').addClass('on-overlay'); // Show the overlay
    } else {
      $('#cn-overlay').removeClass('on-overlay'); // Hide the overlay
    }
    // Close one dropdown when selecting another
    $('.hide').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
      $('.hide').hide();
      $('#cn-overlay').removeClass('on-overlay'); // Hide the overlay
      isDropdownOpen = !isDropdownOpen
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* overlay */

.cn-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  /* top: 0; */
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  /* display: none; */
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Class added to the overlay via JavaScript to show it when navigation is open */

.cn-overlay.on-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper {
  height: 40px;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper ul {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 10;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  user-select: none;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper ul li a i {
  font-size: 12px
}

li.bottom-nav-link div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-inline: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(100px); */
}

li.bottom-nav-link div ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
}


/* li.bottom-nav-link div ul li{
    /* display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
} */

li.bottom-nav-link .link-title {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: montserrat;
}

li.bottom-nav-link div a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 10px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); */
  background-color: var(--md-sys-color-on-surface);
}
```

```html
<div id="cn-overlay" class="cn-overlay"></div>

<div class="bottom-nav">
  <div class="bottom-nav-wrapper">
    <ul id="dropdown-wrapper">
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a class="link-title">
                    tv
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">samsung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">sony</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">jvc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">star</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">pine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">lg</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a href="#!" class="link-title">
                    others
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">x-box</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">speakers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a href="#!" class="link-title">
                    phones
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">huawei</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">oppo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">iphone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">samsung</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a href="#!" class="link-title">clothes<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">socks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">jumpers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">sweaters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">shirts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" />
```

Comment: i had tried to toggle the class but it adds more problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `$('.dropdown .hide').is(':visible')` in the `slideToggle()` callback.
With your permission, I edited only the piece of your javascript code...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown a:not(:only-child)').click(function() {
    $('#cn-overlay').addClass('on-overlay');
    $(this).siblings('.hide').slideToggle(400, function() {
      if ( ! $('.dropdown .hide').is(':visible') ) {
        $('#cn-overlay').removeClass('on-overlay');
      }
     });
    $('.hide').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
    return false;
  });

  // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
      $('.hide').hide();
      $('#cn-overlay').removeClass('on-overlay'); // Hide the overlay
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* overlay */

.cn-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  /* top: 0; */
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  /* display: none; */
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Class added to the overlay via JavaScript to show it when navigation is open */

.cn-overlay.on-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper {
  height: 40px;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper ul {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 10;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  user-select: none;
}

div.bottom-nav-wrapper ul li a i {
  font-size: 12px
}

li.bottom-nav-link div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-inline: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(100px); */
}

li.bottom-nav-link div ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
}


/* li.bottom-nav-link div ul li{
    /* display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
} */

li.bottom-nav-link .link-title {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: montserrat;
}

li.bottom-nav-link div a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 10px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); */
  background-color: var(--md-sys-color-on-surface);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cn-overlay" class="cn-overlay"></div>

<div class="bottom-nav">
  <div class="bottom-nav-wrapper">
    <ul id="dropdown-wrapper">
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a class="link-title">
                    tv
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">samsung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">sony</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">jvc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">star</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">pine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">lg</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a href="#!" class="link-title">
                    others
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">x-box</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">speakers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a href="#!" class="link-title">
                    phones
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">huawei</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">oppo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">iphone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">samsung</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="bottom-nav-link dropdown">
        <a href="#!" class="link-title">clothes<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <div class="hide">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">socks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">jumpers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">sweaters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">shirts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow thanks, this worked perfectly. I had tried to check for :is visible before but not the same way you have.